# I am trying to use TimeDiff to find out the duration between columnA and columnB in Hours

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

(I am trying to use TimeDiff to find out the duration between columnA and columnB in Hours.)

```
SELECT tp.awb_number,
tp.courier_code,
tph.created,
tph.status_date,
    MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(tph.status_date, tph.created))
    FROM shiptrack.tracking_package tp
    INNER JOIN shiptrack.tracking_package_history tph ON tph.tracking_package_id= tp.id
    WHERE  tph.status_date BETWEEN '2016-01-07 12:00:01' AND  '2016-01-07 20:59:59'  
    AND tp.courier_code IN ('ESSKAY') 
    AND tph.new_status='UDL' 
    AND tph.last_status <> tph.new_status
    AND MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(tph.status_date,tph.created))> 30
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: what db you are using mysql or oracle and what problem you are facing.

Comment: AND MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(tph.status_date,tph.created))> 30 (How i can get particular data which are >30 minutes in this code..)